# Kendo tree view drag and drop using same tree componant

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, treeview

I am using Kendo UI for Angular which has tree view drag drop feature.
This requires two tree view to be initialized and the instance of the other to be included in **dropZoneTreeViews** of the first tree.

This works perfectly when I use two tree views in my HTML page and give them each different id to be used.

```
<div>
<kendo-treeview #listA 
    [dropZoneTreeViews]="[listB]" 
    kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop
    kendoTreeViewFlatDataBinding 
                            .
                            .
                            .>
</kendo-treeview>

<kendo-treeview #listB 
    [dropZoneTreeViews]="[listA]" 
    kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop
    kendoTreeViewFlatDataBinding 
                            .
                            .
                            .>
</kendo-treeview>
</div>
```

Now what I need to achieve is to create a separate component for tree view and use it for both the tree views like this

```
<app-tree-view #listA [dropZoneTreeViews]="[listB]"
.
.></app-tree-view> 

<app-tree-view #listB [dropZoneTreeViews]="[listA]
.
."></app-tree-view>
```

I pass the data using **@Input dropZoneTreeViews** for drop zone as well as other data, but am not able to link the two tree views using **dropZoneTreeViews** as it no longer recognizes the instance of the other tree.

How should I proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following.

In your CustomTreeviewComponent add the following ViewChild's:

```
@ViewChild(DragAndDropDirective) dragDrop: DragAndDropDirective;
@ViewChild(TreeViewComponent) treeview: TreeViewComponent;
```

And then in the parent component:

```
@ViewChild('listA') listA: CustomTreeviewComponent;
@ViewChild('listB') listB: CustomTreeviewComponent;
    
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.listA.dragDrop.dropZoneTreeViews.push(this.listB.treeview);
  this.listB.dragDrop.dropZoneTreeViews.push(this.listA.treeview);
}
```